# Prove that every affine set that contains the origin is a subspace.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, economics

I need to solve this:

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space. Prove that every affine set that contains the origin of is a subspace of V.

So I think I see why this is true, I'm just having trouble getting started. If the affine set did not contain the origin, then it wouldn't be closed under scalar multiplication. I assume I need to start by considering we have an affine set containing the origin of V - do I just proceed to showing that this satisfies all the properties of a subspace?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What definition do you have for an affine subset?

Comment: If you work in coordinates, this becomes obvious. An affine subspace has an equation of the form $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a matrix and $x,b$ are vectors. Now, the space is a linear subspace only for $b=0$.

Comment: In response to Bernard, I have the defn. where if for every x,y in a subset, and every t in the reals, tx + (1-t)y is in the subset.